# What is "serviced" in the context of configuring Zenoss dev?

Tags: centos, zenoss

I am following [Zenoss Development Environment Guide](http://zenpacklib.zenoss.com/en/latest/development-environment-5.html) to configure Zenoss. When I get to the part about mounting z directory into container, I cannot find the file mentioned - I've tried "find" and it's just not there. I can't find anything on Google on how to add serviced to the environment, I think partly because searches bring the root word "service" rather than "serviced". Does anyone know what serviced is and how to install it or its substitute for the purpose of the task? Please, see quote below. Thanks much.

...

> Mount “/z” Into All Containers 
>   Now we can configure serviced to
>   automatically share (bind mount) the host’s /z directory into every
>   container it starts. This will let us use the same files on the host
>   and in containers using the exact same path.
>
> Edit /lib/systemd/system/serviced.service. Add a mount argument to the
>   end of the ExecStart line so that it looks like this:
>
> ExecStart=/opt/serviced/bin/serviced --mount *,/z,/z

...

Answer (score 1):

Serviced is command line Docker orchestration tool developed for Zenoss 5. Full name is [Control Center](http://controlcenter.io/). Read [Zenoss 5 installation guide](https://www.zenoss.com/resources/documentation), there is included what do you need for serviced (control center) installation.